# Fish shell "fish_prompt.fish" error

Tags: command-line, apt, themes, sh, fish

```
_tide_remove_unusable_items: command not found
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish (line 5): 
_tide_remove_unusable_items
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish
_tide_cache_variables: command not found
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish (line 6): 
_tide_cache_variables
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish
_tide_parent_dirs: command not found
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish (line 7): 
_tide_parent_dirs
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish
source: Error encountered while sourcing file 'n/a':
source: No such file or directory
_tide_pwd: command not found
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish (line 1): 
_tide_pwd
^~~~~~~~^
in command substitution
    called on line 15 of file ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish
in function 'fish_prompt'
in command substitution
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish (line 15): Unknown command
    string replace @PWD@ (_tide_pwd)  $_tide_prompt_4539[1]' '
                         ^~~~~~~~~~^
in function 'fish_prompt'
in command substitution
fish: Unknown command: _tide_1_line_prompt
fish: 
_tide_1_line_prompt
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
in command substitution
fish: Unknown command
PATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/linuxbrew:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin CMD_DURATION=1042 fish_bind_mode=default set _tide_prompt_4539 (_tide_1_line_prompt)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
_tide_pwd: command not found
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish (line 1): 
_tide_pwd
^~~~~~~~^
in command substitution
    called on line 15 of file ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish
in function 'fish_prompt'
in command substitution
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish (line 15): Unknown command
    string replace @PWD@ (_tide_pwd)  $_tide_prompt_4539[1]' '
                         ^~~~~~~~~~^
in function 'fish_prompt'
in command substitution`
```

This shows up whenever I try using fish on my ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I've used fish before with fisher plugin and it was working just fine, but when I tried to install **omf theme** it didn't work so I ran `omf doctor` and it said to me to remove this file - `~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish`. I think the error showed up after this but I'm not entirely sure.

I can run commands in fish but this code always shows up.
I've tried searching on Internet but I didn't come across any kind of effective solution, I've also tried purging it and then reinstalling it but no change.